# Maven command line build vs Hudson build

Tags: maven, hudson

I run the command `mvn clean package cf:push` on the command line, it works perfectly without any issue. I also have a Hudson installed on the same machine. I use the Hudson Maven plugin to use the same Maven environment and run the same goal `clean package cf:push`, but I got the error below:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.652 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-05T09:01:45+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/357M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - Build failed with exception(s)
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - [1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.1.2:push (default-cli) on project gs-messaging-redis: Execution default-cli of goal org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.1.2:push failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.1.2:push: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

Comment: If you want to run that in Hudson use freestyle type and not MavenJob in Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the logs and i found tricky things below:
if i set the goal for the Hudson like this `clean package cf:push -e`, actually  the commend that was executed by the Hudson like this:

```
mvn clean package cf:push -e -V -B -Dmaven.ext.class.path=/home/dingjianrui/hudson/maven/slavebundle/resources:/home/dingjianrui/hudson/maven/slavebundle/lib/maven3-eventspy-3.1.jar:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/hudson-remoting-3.0.3.jar -Dhudson.eventspy.port=38570 -f pom.xml
```

This command actually injected some other libraries that are especially used by Hudson itself, i guess they are used for remote control and output the log to somewhere, and there is no way i can disable them.

The injected libraries actually have conflict with the maven libraries. That's why i got the warning below:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/dingjianrui/hudson/maven/slavebundle/lib/maven3-eventspy-runtime.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j-simple.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

And it also has conflict with the my plugin libraries, which eventually got the whole things failed.

```
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - [1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.1.2:push (default-cli) on project gs-messaging-redis: Execution default-cli of goal org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.1.2:push failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.cloudfoundry:cf-maven-plugin:1.1.2:push: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

Keep in mind that if i run the same command `mvn clean package cf:push -e` on the command line, everything is ok.
My questions is how to avoid the conflicts between the injected Hudson libraries with my plugins' libraries? and what's is the root cause above?

Thanks.